How to get iformation about the other one of Eggmove's parents?
This article is written in a translator, so it can be difficult to understand.
I found an egg tag on the move-learn-method.
And I've seen that the actor of a particular Pokémon appears as below in the list of skills.


 "version_group_details": [
        {
          "level_learned_at": 0,
          "move_learn_method": {
            "name": "egg",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/2/"
          },
          "version_group": {
            "name": "gold-silver",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/3/"
          }
        },



However, I knew that the technique was learned by crossing, but I didn't know which Pokémon to cross.
Does the api have any list information for opposing pokemon needed to learn mating skills?
What I'm curious about is that it's not registered in the api information?
Or is it something I didn't find?
If it's not registered, I hope it's added and if it's something I haven't found, please let me know how to check.
